# Rendering issue (JPEG artifact on characters mouth/non-transparent background) how do I fix this?

Tags: rendering, transparency, artifacts

I am rendering a Roblox character in Blender to make a GFX. I seem to be continuously running into this issue, no matter how many times I re-render the image. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use jpeg. What you see are compression artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

are you using a jpeg as the mouth's texture, or as render output?

Anyway, jpeg is a really harsh lossy picture format. There is always a quite noticeable loss with it.

I recommend you read the Blender Manual's page about the [Supported Graphics Formats](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/files/media/image_formats.html#supported-graphics-formats). Starting by this very simple yet quite true Hint:

> If you are not interested in technical details, a good rule of thumb for selecting output formats for your project is:
>
> **Use OpenEXR**
>   if you intend to do compositing or color grading on these images.
>   **Use PNG**
>   if you intend on-screen output or encoding into multiple video formats.
>   **Use JPEG**
>   for on-screen output where file size is a concern and quality loss is acceptable.
>
> All these formats support compression which can be important when rendering out animations.

TL;DR : don't use jpeg if you care about quality.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks for the answer.